# Revoke PRIVILEGES on schema and tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I want to revoke all the privileges of following commands How should I do this? using postgresql

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA  "school" to integration;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA school TO user_1;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA school TO user_1;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA school TO user_1;
```

Also how to GRANT a permission to particular table? following errors that relation "schemautution.mobile" does not exist

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON schemautution.mobile TO school;
```

And REVOKE a permisson to a particulat table? This following errors that
 relation "schemautution.mobile" does not exist

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON schemautution.mobile TO school;
```

Also want to apply, following but throws error that it relation "schemautution.mobile" does not exist how to fix  this?

```
ALTER SEQUENCE schemautution.mobile SET SCHEMA school;
```

how to revoke/delete this all permissions to associated schema commands?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: check for uppercase schema/table name and use double quotes around if it is the case

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL, replace GRANT by REVOKE and TO by FROM:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA  "school" FROM integration;
REVOKE

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA school FROM user_1;
REVOKE

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA school FROM user_1;
REVOKE

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA school FROM user_1;
REVOKE
```

Comment: How to revoke PRIVILEGES on a particular table?

Comment: You can do it the same way: use REVOKE statement instead of GRANT.

Comment: You cannot revoke privilege on non existing objects.

Comment: How can i revoke access to a particualr table?

Comment: It's always the same way: for every GRANT statement related to this table you need to run the corresponding REVOKE statement. AFAIK there is no single REVOKE command for a given table.